# How do I change the tint and background tint of the fab in the main activities?

Tags: android, xml, google-play, apk, floating-action-button

I can't run my app because when I add a backgroundTint I get an error upon running my app.

Please someone help, here is my main activity file, where the fab is located.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XVla.jpg

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>
```

Comment: Check your google repository are updated to latest version and share your defaultConfig

Answer (score 0):

go to sdk manager>sdk tools>google play services
update it